# Trying to understand how Apache Arrow's in-memory store works

Tags: memory, apache-arrow

Apache Arrow is an in-memory serialization format. Part of Arrow is [Plasma](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/08/08/plasma-in-memory-object-store/), an in-memory object store designed to share data efficiently among processes on the same machine. I want to get a better understanding of what this is.

My first-order approximation of how this would work is by putting the Arrow serialized data in shared memory (in the IPC sense) and allow multiple processes to read (but not write) from it. Is this roughly all there is to the Plasma in-memory store? Or is there something more complicated that's happening under the hood?

My suspicion is that Plasma efficiently maps only the specific part of the in-memory Arrow data structure that is needed by the process into said process' address space.

Comment: I am also looking for using Arrow to allow multiple processes to read while one process to write/update.  Any finding to share?  Thanks!